# WSO2. How to transform the SOAP message in XML and send it to the service?

Tags: wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

Good day!

I recently started studying WSO ESB

My service receives requests and responds in XML format, example:

> ```
> <!--The query in my service -->
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
> Content-Length: 109     
> <req>
>   <Value>How are you?</Value>
> </req>
>
> <!--The response from the service -->
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Length: 120
> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8    
> <res>
> <Value>Very good!!!</Value>
> </res>
> ```

I need to transform a SOAP request from a client via a proxy service to and from XML in the SOAP client

Example SOAP request and response in proxyservice

> ```
> <!--The request from the client to proxy service-->
> <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
>   <soap:Body>
>     <Question xmlns="http://MyTestService">
>        <Value>How are you?</Value>
>     </Question>
>   </soap:Body>
> </soap:Envelope>
>
> <!--Answer the service proxy to the client-->
> <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>   <s:Body>
>     <QuestionResponse xmlns="http://CyberPlatService">
>       <Fun1Result>Very good!!!</Fun1Result>
>     </QuestionResponse>
>   </s:Body>
> </s:Envelope>
> ```

Here is my proxy service

> ```
> <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="CyberPlatProxy" transports="https http" 
>        startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
>   <target>
>     <inSequence>
>       <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
>         <format>
>           <req>
>             <Value>$1</Value>
>           </req>
>         </format>
>         <args>
>           <arg  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>           expression="//Question/Value"/>
>         </args>
>       </payloadFactory>
>       <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
>       <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
>       <log level="custom"/>
>       <send>
>         <endpoint>
>           <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:2009/"/>
>         </endpoint>
>       </send>
>     </inSequence>
>     <outSequence>
>       <payloadFactory media-type="xml" description="res">
>         <format>
>           <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>             <s:Body>
>               <GetStaysResponse xmlns="http://CyberPlatService">
>                 <GetStaysResult>$1</GetStaysResult>
>               </GetStaysResponse>
>             </s:Body>
>           </s:Envelope>
>         </format>
>         <args>
>           <arg expression="//Value"/>
>         </args>
>       </payloadFactory>
>       <property name="messageType" value="application/soap+xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
>       <send/>
>     </outSequence>
>     <faultSequence/>
>   </target>
> </proxy>
> ```

Nothing happens, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The "Question" node belongs to `http://MyTestService` namespace so, your xpath `//Question/Value` can't work, you should change :

```
<arg  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" expression="//Question/Value"/>
```

to :

```
<arg  xmlns:test="http://MyTestService" expression="//test:Question/test:Value/text()"/>
```